# Uncaught TypeError: this._updateBounds is not a function when i hover over the bar-chart

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

When I mouseover any portion of the bar chart which was created through the Data visualization Frame work plugin for leaflet this error message( same as the one in the question) shows up. Here is my Html and JavaScript code 
HTML Code:

```
        <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <!--leafletCss-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="leaflet.css">
        <!--Javascriptlink-->
        <script src="leaflet.js"></script>
        <!-- dvf link from internet-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dvf.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet-dvf/0.3.1/leaflet-dvf.markers.js" integrity="sha256-NWe8/8nwSWLS01t+tEKiSi5++ddqxqHp8mDjd8o+fbg=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Css for the home button-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!--Css link-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="def_leaflet_css.css">
        <!--Css link for the home button on the map-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet.zoomhome.css">
        <!--Css link for the FullScreen-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Control.FullScreen.css">

        <!--Css link for the timeslider-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
        <!--Home button javascript java script-->
        <script src="leaflet.zoomhome.min.js"></script>
        <!--Fullscreen java script-->
        <script src="Control.FullScreen.js"></script>
        <!--timerange java script-->
        <script src="leaflet.SliderControl.min.js"></script>
        <script src="SliderControl.js"></script>
        <!--timeline2 java script-->
        <title>def_example</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class=Head>
         <h1>dvf</h1>
       </div>
       <br>
       <br>
       <div id="Map">
       </div>
        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <!-- The scripts are jquery for slider2-->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap Jquery optional
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script src="leaflet-timeline-slider.min.js"></script>
        <script src="def_leaflet_js_example.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Javascript code:

```
        // Declaring important variables
    var myLat=31.1704;
    var myLong=72.7097;
    var zoom=5;
    //var myLat=43.8476
    //var myLong=18.3564
    //var zoom=13
    var ScaleFactor=0.2
    // declaring the map
    var map=L.map('Map',{zoomControl: false,fullscreenControl:true,fullscreenControlOptions: {position:'topleft'}}).setView([myLat,myLong],zoom);
    //map tile layer
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { 
            attribution:'&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors', 
            minZoom:2
            //maxBounds: mybounds
    }).addTo(map);
    var options = {
        data: {
            'dataPoint1': Math.random() * 20,
            'dataPoint2': Math.random() * 20,
            'dataPoint3': Math.random() * 20,
            'dataPoint4': Math.random() * 20
        },
        chartOptions: {
            'dataPoint1': {

                minValue: 0,
                maxValue: 20,
                maxHeight: 20,
                displayText: function (value) {
                    return value.toFixed(2);
                }
            },
            'dataPoint2': {

                minValue: 0,
                maxValue: 20,
                maxHeight: 20,
                displayText: function (value) {
                    return value.toFixed(2);
                }
            },
            'dataPoint3': {

                minValue: 0,
                maxValue: 20,
                maxHeight: 20,
                displayName: 'Romney',
                displayText: function (value) {
                    return value;
                }
            },
            'dataPoint4': {

                minValue: 0,
                maxValue: 20,
                maxHeight: 20,
                displayText: function (value) {
                    return value;
                }
            }
        },
    }

    var barChartMarker = new L.BarChartMarker(new L.LatLng(31.1704, 72.7097), options);
    barChartMarker.on({
        mouseover(e){
            this.bindTooltip("lala")
        },
        mouseout(e){
            this.closePopup()
        }
    })
    map.addLayer(barChartMarker);
```

SO When I run this code with the html it successfully creates  a bar-chart. But the moment i Bring the mouse on the bar-chart this error shows up[This is the map with the error message shown in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkxWe.png)